# Pyomo (using couenne) cannot optimize powers >= 3

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I have a MINLP problem to solve and couenne crashes when I try to optimize it. I managed to reduce it significally while still crashing and found a possible culprit.

The reduced problem objective function is an alternating polinomial `x[n] - x[n-1] + x[n-2] - ...`. There is a single array of variables `x[k], k=n..1` where the index indicate the exponent of x. There is also a restriction array enforcing this exponentiation.

For powers greater than 2:

- If I directly exponentiate `x[k] = x[1]**k`, couenne crastses.
- If I cascade exponents `x[k] = x[k-1]*x[1]`, couenne solves normally.

So my questions are: What's the difference from the solver point of view? Is this failure to be expected? Should I recompile couenne with another dependency?

- My enviroment is Ubuntu 18.04.
- I'm using Pyomo 5.5 (CPython 3.6.5 on Linux 4.15.0-29-generic) installed via conda.
- I've compiled couenne myself using the default flags and downloading the following dependencies (ThirdParties, all downloaded using the wget script provided by the repository): ASL, Blas, Lapack, Metis and Mumps. I didn't download HSL, SCIP and SoPlex.

Here is the test code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import pyomo.environ
import pyomo.core as pc
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

def run(max_pow, cascade):
  model = pc.ConcreteModel()
  model.s = pc.RangeSet(1, max_pow)
  model.x = pc.Var(model.s, bounds=(-1,1))

  model.s_rest = pc.Set(initialize=list(ii for ii in model.s)[1:])

  ## TWO DIFFERENT WAYS OF COMPUTING POWERS ##
  if cascade: # x[k] = x[k-1]*x[1]
    model.x_c = pc.Constraint(model.s_rest, rule=lambda m, s: m.x[s] == m.x[1]*m.x[s-1])
  else:       # x[k] = x[1]**k
    model.x_c = pc.Constraint(model.s_rest, rule=lambda m, s: m.x[s] == m.x[1]**s)

  # Alternating objective function: x[k] - x[k-1] + x[k-2] - ....
  def obj(x, s, pos=True):
    result = x[s]
    if s > 1:
      result = result + obj(x, s-1, not pos)
    if not pos:
      result = -result
    return result

  model.objective = pc.Objective(rule=lambda m: obj(m.x, max_pow), sense=pc.maximize)

  opt = SolverFactory("couenne")
  results = opt.solve(model)

  model.display()

# Test 3 different cases
for max_pow, cascade in [(2, False,), (3, False,), (3, True)]:
  print("\nDegree: {}, cascade: {}".format(max_pow, cascade))
  print("-"*25)
  try:
    run(max_pow, cascade)
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Here are the results:

```
Degree: 2, cascade: False
-------------------------
Model unknown

  Variables:
    x : Size=2, Index=s
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :    -1 :  -1.0 :     1 : False : False :  Reals
          2 :    -1 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False :  Reals

  Objectives:
    objective : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True :   2.0

  Constraints:
    x_c : Size=1
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          2 :   0.0 :  0.0 :   0.0

Degree: 3, cascade: False
-------------------------
ERROR: Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (-11)
ERROR: Solver log: Couenne 0.5 -- an Open-Source solver for Mixed Integer
    Nonlinear Optimization Mailing list: couenne@list.coin-or.org
    Instructions: http://www.coin-or.org/Couenne couenne:
Solver (asl) did not exit normally

Degree: 3, cascade: True
-------------------------
Model unknown

  Variables:
    x : Size=3, Index=s
        Key : Lower : Value                  : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          1 :    -1 :  -0.002154434679988468 :     1 : False : False :  Reals
          2 :    -1 :  4.641588790337013e-06 :     1 : False : False :  Reals
          3 :    -1 : -9.999999860147783e-09 :     1 : False : False :  Reals

  Objectives:
    objective : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
        Key  : Active : Value
        None :   True : 0.002149783091198271

  Constraints:
    x_c : Size=2
        Key : Lower : Body : Upper
          2 :   0.0 :  0.0 :   0.0
          3 :   0.0 :  0.0 :   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Pyomo tends to send the model to the solver exactly as you have formulated it, unless you apply some high-level transformation (as in GDP or DAE).

For many solvers, an expression of the form `x * x * x` is handled differently from `x ** 3`. In some systems, even `x ** 2`, `pow(x, 2)`, and `sqr(x)` give you different behavior. While mathematically equivalent, handling of bounding behavior and domain restrictions may be different.

Comment: @jabozzo Did this hint solve you issue? Just curious...